# Unc0ver Xcode Sideload: Unable to Install

Tags: ios, xcode, jailbreak, sideloading

Sideloading with Xcode results in an "unable to install" popup despite saying the app finished running. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: make sure your provisioning profile in iOS App Signer is selected to your app's "iOS Team Provisioning File" and NOT "Re-Sign Only"